# How to create a targeted dacpac without complications for ASP.NET Core web app and SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, github, .net-core, dacpac

My yaml github workflow deployment build fails for actions/setup-dotnet@v1 looking for an unloaded SQL Server project. I don't understand why the build machine expects a SQL Server project file. I "Unloaded" the SQL Server project from my Visual Studio solution after creating the dacpac and before pushing. The same solution (now only .NET Core project with the unloaded SQL Server project) builds on my machine. The only reason I created the SQL Server project was for the dacpac.

```
C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\NuGet.targets(290,5): error MSB3202: The project file "D:\a\rollbase\Database-Proj\Database-Proj.sqlproj" was not found. [D:\a\rollbase\rollbase\rollbase.sln]

Build FAILED.
```

Deleting the sql project to produce single proj solution builds successfully on github. So somewhere a reference to the unloaded project exists if it remains visible in VS Solution Explorer. Meaning the only way I can get the runner to build my solution is to delete the sql project after producing the dacpac each time. This seems clumsy and still leaves me not understanding the error.

This fairly recent post [Developer Community Issue 2020](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/dotnetcore-build-step-cant-find-csproj-file-listen/1015005) seems to indicate the same kind of problem but opposite fail situation. Though it doesn't help to only be able to read one half of the conversation.

Has anyone got a solution for my github DOTNET_VERSION: '5.0.400 build or a better process for getting a targeted dacpac during database updates for a net core solution? I would appreciate any input.

Comment: Maybe you can use this, if I understand your question: https://erikej.github.io/efcore/2020/05/11/ssdt-dacpac-netcore.html

Comment: Thanks @marc_s Yes I think you understand my question. While ssdt-dacpac-netcore blog is for cross platform implementation I still think it will be useful.